# Angular: Router navigate not returning to root url

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

My router is somehow getting confused when I use one of my components.  For the most part, in my app, if I do something like `this.router.navigateByUrl ('/search');` the router properly navigates to `<root url>/search`.

The problematic route is set up like this:

```
{
    path: 'search',
    component: PlatSearchComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'view/:id',
        component: PlatViewComponent
      },
    ]
},
```

In PlatSearchComponent html:

```
...
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
...
```

Clicking on a row in a table opens the PlatViewComponent as follows:

```
this.router.navigateByUrl (`/search/view/${row.PlatID}`);
```

This correctly opens the PlatViewComponent with a url like `<url root>/search/view/16`.

The problem is, when I navigate away from that page by calling `this.router.navigateByUrl('/search')` from the PlatViewComponent, the URL now becomes `<url root>/search/view/search`.  Continuing to open up a PlatViewComponent results in a URL eventually looking like `<url root>/search/view/search/view/search/view/search/view`...

None of the other components and routes in the app have this problem, navigation between them works as expected.

I don't see any router subscription events or specific route configuration items that would be potentially causing this.

Answer (score 0):

This ended up being an issue with the APP_BASE_HREF of my module.  I was using `./` as the value, changing it to `/` fixed the issue.